# What are the momentary switches in Dangerous Music Source?

Tags: switches, identification, components

I have a Dangerous Music Source. One of the momentary push buttons started to fail (I have to push it so hard to work that I'm afraid of breaking something else... I tried to re-solder it, but it seems to be an internal issue).

These buttons have an integrated LED (green in the case of my broken one). They have 4 pins to the circuit board, 2 rear ones for the contact, and 2 front ones for the led.

The space between the 2 front pins (LED) is 6mm.

The space between the 2 rear pins (contact) is 4.4mm.

The space between the row of 2 front pins and 2 rear pins is 5mm.

The width of the dark-gray plastic casing of the button is 7.5mm.

I am attaching **3 photos** (downscaled to 1024 pixels wide) that show the button in details (I have removed the button cover and placed it on the board nearby).

[image: photo 1 of switches]

[image: photo 2 of switches]

[image: photo 3 of switches]

Due to the Stack Exchange 2MB limit on image file size, the full resolution images are on my website here: https://florianbador.com/pub/dangerous-music-source-broken-switch/

What are these switches? Where can I find them?

Comment: What on earth is a dangerous music source?

Comment: A manufacture would really help, are there any identifying marks? If not, Digikey has a parametric search, good luck: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/pushbutton-switches/199

Comment: It's just right-angle, through-hole mount tactile switches with integrated LED + a plastic cap. You don't actually need the LED though, it's just fluff. And you can toss on any switch there, the footprint should be somewhat standardized.

Answer (score 5):

I did an image search for "illuminated tactile switch"

It looks like the SPJ series by Shanpu:

https://www.shanpu.com.tw/en/product/tags/1/Tactile-Tact-switchees

More precisely the SPJP3******** based on the documentation.

Comment: Voltage isn't a spec for LEDs as it varies too much across the lot. Manufacturers specify the current and the circuit has to supply that one at maximum.

Comment: @FlorianB Be sceptical when they only list mechanical life or only electrical life. Usually means that the one not listed is subpar.

Comment: I couldn't find any retailers, perhaps contact "dangerous" and ask them to supply the repair part?